# ASP.net core api cant add printer

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, rest, asp.net-core

I made a program which prints on a specific printer, but I have multiple printers to setup, so I thought that I will make the site from where they print, do it for me. I have tried to do it via. powershell etc., and it works, just not in my .net core api, but it works in my .net core console. I have given the IUSR rights to manage printers, ports etc. It can make the printer port, but not create the printer. When I used powershell, I got that "Add-Printer" didn't exist, and I tried putting it in powershell myself, and it worked perfectly.. Here is my code:

```
        class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        IntPtr mystrptr = new IntPtr(0);
        bool mysend;
        IntPtr mysend2;
        PRINTER_INFO_2 pi = new PRINTER_INFO_2();
        string printer = "05_Vognmodtagelse_Label";

        pi.pPrinterName = printer;
        pi.pPortName = printer;
        pi.pDriverName = "Brother PT-P950NW";
        pi.pDevMode = mystrptr;
        pi.pPrintProcessor = "WinPrint";
        pi.pDatatype = "RAW";
        pi.pSecurityDescriptor = mystrptr;
        mysend2 = AddPrinter(null, 2, ref pi);

    }

    [DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr AddPrinter(string pName, uint Level, [In] ref PRINTER_INFO_2 pPrinter);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    struct PRINTER_INFO_2
    {
        public string pServerName,
                      pPrinterName,
                      pShareName,
                      pPortName,
                      pDriverName,
                      pComment,
                      pLocation;
        public IntPtr pDevMode;
        public string pSepFile,
                      pPrintProcessor,
                      pDatatype,
                      pParameters;
        public IntPtr pSecurityDescriptor;
        public uint Attributes,
                      Priority,
                      DefaultPriority,
                      StartTime,
                      UntilTime,
                      Status,
                      cJobs,
                      AveragePPM;
    }
}
```

Note: It is the code from the console app.

Comment: Is the printer attached to the server or to the client? And what exactly does _"It can make the printer port, but not create the printer"_ mean?

Comment: The printer is attached to the server

Comment: It runs a command to create the tcp port in powershell before this, and it works perfectly.

Comment: I'm asking what doesn't work about this. What does `AddPrinter()` return, what's the latest error?

Comment: It returns code 0, so it should be successful.